# How to import module only when I need to use it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I have a project which has optional dependencies, depending on the use case it may need `torch` library.  PyTorch takes a lot of memory, it's not optimal to install it when you don't need to use it. In my project, there are parts of the code which use `torch`, but most of the logic does not need it. I'm trying to implement optional import so that when I need to use `torch` I use it, here is my idea:

```py
def _lazy_import_torch():
    import torch

def main():
    _lazy_import_torch()
    print(f'You have torch: {torch.__version__}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this code it appears that `torch` was not imported:

```sh
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 6, in main
    print(f'You have torch: {torch.__version__}')
NameError: name 'torch' is not defined
```

`torch` is installed in my environment.

I was wondering why it did not work and how can I make it works, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code makes `torch` a *local* name of the `_lazy_import_torch` function:

```
def _lazy_import_torch():
    import torch
```

After it's executed, this name is gone, so you won't be able to access it anywhere *outside* this function.

You could return `torch` from the function and then pass it around everywhere:

```
def _lazy_import_torch():
    import torch
    return torch

def main():
    torch = _lazy_import_torch()
    print(f'You have torch: {torch.__version__}')
```

---

Or use a global variable:

```
torch = None

def _lazy_import_torch():
    global torch
    import torch
```

If the module hasn't been imported yet, you'll get an error every time you try to use it, but after you run `_lazy_import_torch`, the global name `torch` will refer to the `torch` module.

---

Here's an example with the CSV module from the standard library:

```
>>> csv = None
>>> def import_csv():
...   global csv
...   import csv
... 
>>> csv
>>> import_csv()
>>> csv
<module 'csv' from '.../lib/python3.9/csv.py'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it, torch will be added to `sys.modules` but won't be visible using the name `torch` outside of the function where you imported it. You could look it up in the other functions using `sys.modules['torch']`.

If it's only used in one or two functions then you could import it at the top of those functions. You only pay the import cost once as after that it's just pulled from `sys.modules`. Doing that in a lot of functions would start to look very messy though.

Comment: I need to import `torch` in many functions, to avoid code multiplication I would like to keep this import in a separate function

Comment: Would it be a good idea to call `_lazy_import_torch()` and then search for `torch` in `sys.modules` manually?

Comment: The central issue really is that you need to do *something* at the top of each function that wants to use torch. Whether that's doing the import or looking it up in `sys.modules` (and hoping you've already done the import) or something else, you've still got a line or two that you're going to duplicate into every function that wants to use torch. The only way not to do this would be the global variable approach mentioned in the other answer, which may be what you're looking for.

Comment: right, I think I'll use global vars, one thing that I don't like about it is that my code linter is not able to catch cases when `torch` is used but was not yet imported, but it's just a whim